# How to debug a Rust .a file in Swift via FFI and set breakpoints?

Tags: swift, rust

I am currently working on a project that requires me to call a Rust .a file from Swift using FFI. I have managed to successfully call the functions in Rust, however, I am encountering difficulties when it comes to debugging the Rust code once it's invoked from Swift.

Comment: You need to package your dylib into a framework and them package it together with the dSYM into an XCFramework. (And of course you need to be compiling on the same machine where you are debugging)